# Finding the data inside a word document

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project which I'm doing, I have to find if my word document consists of any image or table. Is there any way to do that using c# code. I couldn't find any code related to this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try bellow code.....

```
Use Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

This code work in asp.net and winforms, but I test it on Windows XP Pro, I don't know it work on Windows Server

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;
using Page=System.Web.UI.Page;

public partial class DefaultPage : Page {
    private Application m_word;
    private int m_i;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        object fileName = "C:\\Test.docx";
        m_word = new Application();
        m_word.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < m_word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count; i++) {
                m_i = i;
                Thread thread = new Thread(CopyFromClipboardInlineShape);
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < m_word.ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count; i++) {
                m_i = i;
                Thread thread = new Thread(CopyFromClipboardShape);
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
            }
        }
        finally {
            object save = false;
            m_word.Quit(ref save, ref missing, ref missing);
            m_word = null;
        }
    }

    protected void CopyFromClipboardInlineShape() {
        InlineShape inlineShape = m_word.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes[m_i];
        inlineShape.Select();
        m_word.Selection.Copy();
        Computer computer = new Computer();
        Image img = computer.Clipboard.GetImage();
        /*...*/
    }

    protected void CopyFromClipboardShape() {
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        object i = m_i + 1;
        Shape shape = m_word.ActiveDocument.Shapes.get_Item(ref i);
        shape.Select(ref missing);
        m_word.Selection.Copy();
        Computer computer = new Computer();
        Image img = computer.Clipboard.GetImage();
        /*...*/
    }
}
```